# Add custom emoji marker on Mapbox in react native

Tags: react-native, mapbox, emoji, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-marker

I want to add custom emoji marker on Mapbox in my react native project. Can someone guide me or explain how to add the marker? I am using @react-native-mapbox-gl/maps

Comment: What have you tried so far? Code snippets would also be helpful.